# ¿Como copiar un archivo de un directorio a otro con PHP?

Tags: php, archivo, php5

Tengo 2 sitios web en el mismo servidor linux, pero como es logico,estan diferentes carpetas, con este codigo puedo copiar archivos dentro de un mismo dominio por asi decirlo. ¿Como puedo copiar un archivo de un dominio a otro? y en caso que tenga que usar ftp, solo puedo usar sftp.

```
$fichero = 'ejemplo.txt';
$nuevo_fichero = 'carpeta/ejemplo.txt'; // esta es la carpeta dentro del mismo dominio
//me gustaria poder escribir algo como: /var/www/html/carpetadestino/ejemplo.txt

if (!copy($fichero, $nuevo_fichero)) {
    echo "Error al copiar $fichero...\n";
}
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco si ambos archivos están el mismo servidor el código mostrado debería funcionar

Comment: No funciona, el dominio 1 esta en: /var/www/dominio1/ y el dominio 2 esta en: /var/www/html/. Con ese codigo de arriba solo he podido copiar archivos en directorios dentro de html o de dominio1. pero no fuera como en /www/ o del directorio de un dominio a otro.

Comment: Ambos están en el directorio `/www/`, por lo que simplemente retroceda en los directorios, por ejemplo: `../www/carpetaAlaQueQuieraCopiar`

Comment: Tienes razón, al parecer era un problema de permisos. Gracias

Comment: Lo paso a respuesta para que si alguien tiene el mismo problema pueda solucionarlo! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ambos archivos están el mismo servidor el código mostrado debería funcionar...
Ambos están en el directorio /www/, por lo que simplemente retroceda en los directorios, por ejemplo: `../www/carpetaAlaQueQuieraCopiar`